# How to create a table with quarters and customers who didn't order in this quarter - MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

The table I have is basically a sales history table from the Adventure Works sample database, basically `salesorderheader (CustomerID, OrderDate, ... )`. I want to find out those customers who didn't order in every quarter and I want to know which quarter they didn't order. I can get the answer in the following cumbersome manner with `UNION` clause:

```
select distinct CustomerID, 1 as quarter
from salesorderheader
where CustomerID not in (select distinct CustomerID 
                         from salesorderheader
                         where quarter(OrderDate) = 1)

union 

select distinct CustomerID, 2 as quarter
from salesorderheader
where CustomerID not in (select distinct CustomerID 
                         from salesorderheader
                         where quarter(OrderDate) = 2)

union

select distinct CustomerID, 3 as quarter
from salesorderheader
where CustomerID not in (select distinct CustomerID 
                         from salesorderheader
                         where quarter(OrderDate) = 3)

union

select distinct CustomerID, 4 as quarter
from salesorderheader
where CustomerID not in (select distinct CustomerID 
                         from salesorderheader
                         where quarter(OrderDate) = 4)
order by CustomerID, quarter;
```

And I can get the table like:

```
CustomerID, quarter
19, 1
19, 3
19, 4
26, 3
31, 1
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t2.CustomerID, t1.`Quarter`
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS `Quarter` UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
  FROM salesorderheader
) AS t2 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerID, QUARTER(OrderDate) AS `Quarter`
  FROM salesorderheader
) AS t3 ON t2.CustomerID = t3.CustomerID 
           AND t1.`Quarter` = t3.`Quarter`  
WHERE t3.`Quarter` IS NULL
ORDER BY t2.CustomerID
```

`CROSS JOIN` of derived tables `t1`, `t2` essentially creates a table containing all possible combinations of quarters and customers ids.

If we perform a `LEFT JOIN` of this table with the original table, i.e. `salesorderheader`, we can easily find which of the combinations are missing using `t3.Quarter IS NULL` predicate.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11b74/1)

Comment: Thank you, Giorgos! I had a similar idea but failed to come up with a cross join solution like you posted.

Comment: @user5349118 Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please mark this  or any other answer as accepted if it really helped you solve your problem.